# Oracle query joins are not supported by cucumber test cases

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

in cucumber junit test cases , when we try to run the test cases, it is failing on the entity layer because of joins in the oracle sql queries.

Cucumber is using different db. What is the way to change the inbuilt db of cucumber. Or any other solutions to overcome this failure.

Comment: For this reason, you should always use the same database for development and testing.

Comment: i should have to use oracle db only. so need to change the inbuilt db in cucumber. How to achieve it

Comment: Cucumber does not have any in-built db. Can u explain a bit more ,preferably with some relevant code, what u r trying to achieve?

Comment: h2 db is the one which is being getting used now.
 
      <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.197</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

Comment: EmbeddedDatabase db = builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2);
How to change this to oracle db